# Best way to store logs in production

Tags: spring-boot

Whats the best approach to store error logs in the production environment. Storing logs in the database? in file? on console?  I'm using messagesource to return server error message.

Thanks.

Comment: Use logstash or something similar. Voting to  close as opinion based